# chcon: failed to change context of ‘archivejson.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

When I run:

```
chcon -R -t http_sys_content_t /usr/local/nagios/sbin/
```

I get the following errors:

```
chcon: failed to change context of ‘archivejson.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘avail.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘cmd.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘config.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘extinfo.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘histogram.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘history.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘notifications.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘objectjson.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘outages.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘showlog.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘status.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘statusjson.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘statusmap.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘statuswml.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘statuswrl.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘summary.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘tac.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘trends.cgi’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
chcon: failed to change context of ‘/usr/local/nagios/sbin/’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:http_sys_content_t:s0’: Invalid argument
```

How can I fix it and what causes this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such type `http_sys_content_t`.

Did you intend to use `httpd_sys_content_t` instead?

Comment: nice. I was following a video which was for an older version of CentOS. Thanks! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtaSY1ALZzE